# MVC 3 - RequiredAttribute - Override based on session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model like this with a couple of fields such as name, email and phone.
All of these are set with the [Required] attribute.

What I would like to do is override the RequiredAttribute and only require the property if the current visitor of the website is not an administrator.  So basically an administrator can type what they like or leave a field empty where as normal users cannot.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or advise on the best way to acheive this ?

To find out if a visitor is admin I use:

```
var permissionId = Helpers.ConvertToInt(Services.UserService.GetCurrentPermissionId().ToString());
```

If this is 0 or 1 then the visitor is not an administrator so the field should be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking into using [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) which will allow you to specify much more complicated rules then the built in data annotations allow without having to build custom attributes.

You could then solve this by using syntax similar to this:

```
RuleFor(obj => obj.Email).NotEmpty().Unless(obj => Helpers.ConvertToInt(Services.UserService.GetCurrentPermissionId()) > 1)
```

Comment: I could not get the "Unless" to work, it seemed to only beable to use a model property rather than a variable. I got this to work by wrapping the RuleFor around a If statement.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a custom conditional validation attribute:

```
public class RequiredIfPermissionIdsAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public int[] PermissionIds { get; private set; }

    public RequiredIfPermissionIdsAttribute(params int[] permissionIds)
    {
        PermissionIds = permissionIds ?? new int[0];
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        int permissionId = Helpers.ConvertToInt(Services.UserService.GetCurrentPermissionId().ToString());

        if (PermissionIds.Contains(permissionId))
        {
            return base.IsValid(value);
        }

        // the current permission id is not in the list of permission ids
        // that require validation => we consider the model valid
        return true;
    }
}
```

and then you could decorate your property with this attribute:

```
[RequiredIfPermissionIds(0, 1)]
public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

Alternatively instead of using a blacklist  approach you could use a whitelist approach:

```
public class NotRequiredIfPermissionIdsAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public NotRequiredIfPermissionIdsAttribute(params int[] permissionIds)
    {
        PermissionIds = permissionIds ?? new int[0];
    }

    public int[] PermissionIds { get; private set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        int permissionId = Helpers.ConvertToInt(Services.UserService.GetCurrentPermissionId().ToString());

        if (!PermissionIds.Contains(permissionId))
        {
            return base.IsValid(value);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
[NotRequiredIfPermissionIds(2)]
public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

Comment: If you want to extend the validation to the client side you will need to also override the GetClientValidationRules and conditionally do base.GetClientValidationRules or not depending on if there are matches or not.

Comment: I like this solution but I need it to work on client side also, can anyone show me how the override of the GetClientValidationRules would work. I tried this but kept running into issues.

Comment: This is possible by implementing the `IClientValidatable` interface but how do you intend to call the `Helpers.ConvertToInt(Services.UserService.GetCurrentPermissionId().ToString());` method in javascript? That certainly is not possible. You could use the `[Remote]` attribute to securely perform this validation on the server. That is something that I definitely do not recommend you implementing on the client.